# XNextEvent is not returning?

Tags: c, xorg

I am new to programming in c and with xorg-server. I wish to make anything but XNextEvent will only return the first three times it is called. After that it does return anymore until I envoke some event such as resizing the window or going fullscreen. So if the window is at a standstil, XNextEvent will not return. This has to be some obvious error on my part right? Source Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>

#define WIDTH 1000
#define HEIGHT 600
#define CELL_SIZE 10

Display *dis;
int screen;
Window win;
XEvent event;
GC gc;

void init(){
    dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (dis == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display");
        exit(1);
    }
    screen = DefaultScreen(dis);
    
    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(
        dis,
        RootWindow(dis, screen),
        100, 100, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1,
        BlackPixel(dis, screen),
        WhitePixel(dis, screen)
    );

    XSelectInput(dis, win, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);
    gc = XCreateGC(dis, win, 0, 0);
    XSetBackground(dis, gc, WhitePixel(dis, screen));
    XSetForeground(dis, gc, BlackPixel(dis, screen));
    XClearWindow(dis, win);
    XMapRaised(dis, win);
}

void close_program(){
    XFreeGC(dis, gc);
    XDestroyWindow(dis, win);
    XCloseDisplay(dis);
    exit(0);
}

int main(){
    init();

    while (1){
        XNextEvent(dis, &event);
        if (event.type == Expose){
            printf("Will this execute? Prolly not.\n");
        }
            printf("Will this execute? no.\n");
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I know Im not using the `close_program` function, still figuring it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no event pending in the queue, XNextEvent will block until there is one. That is what the [documentation](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XNextEvent.3.xhtml) says.

Comment: smh. I should've check the documentation before posting this. I guess I know for next time thank you for the quick response though!